# Passing data between PHP files

Tags: php, http, header

Here I have foo.php that runs in the background without any HTML, it's never visited by the user.

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['data'])) {

 $bar = $_GET['data']; // data comes from a html form on another page.

 $str = strtoupper($bar);

 echo $str;
}
```

This is just a simple example, but let's say I wan't to pass `$str` to another file, `script.php` for extra processing.

What's the best method for this? The only way I can think of doing this is by posting it into a database and then retrieving it inside of `script.php` ?

Comment: I would include the file `foo.php` in the file `script.php` and make a function out of the if statement!

Comment: $_SESSION["FOO"] = $bar;

Comment: Is your question answered? Or do you need more information/ examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is probebly a easy way to do it:

You can make a function out of the if statement

foo.php:

```
<?php
    function fooFunction() {
        if (isset($_GET['data'])) {

            $bar = $_GET['data']; // data comes from a html form on another page.
            $str = strtoupper($bar);

            return $str;
        }
    }
?>
```

script.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'foo.php';

?>
```

OR if you already have a session you can insert it into the session array like this:

foo.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['data'])) {

        $bar = $_GET['data']; // data comes from a html form on another page.
        $str = strtoupper($bar);

        $_SESSION['str'] = $str;
    }
?>
```

script.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo $_SESSION['str'];

?>
```

Comment: Never, _ever_ `echo` in a function... functions `return`, it's up to the caller to decide what to do with the return value, echo it or assign it to a variable for later use

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem wups jeah thanks forgot it to change it after copying it

Answer (score 3):

**Using Session:**

```
//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $bar;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

Remember to run the session_start() statement on both these pages before you try to access the        $_SESSION array, and also before any output is sent to the browser.

**Cookie:**

```
//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $bar;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

As @ Rizier123 mentioned "**Cookies can be deleted or disabled! Wouldn't do that if the variable is very important** ". So better avoid this approach.

Comment: Cookies can be deleted or disabled! Wouldn't do that if the variable is very important

Answer (score 1):

If you `include` (or `require`) a php script X into another php script Y, Y will have acces to all X datas and functions. You could also use sessions like @sanki commented.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that could be useful for you:

- [include](http://php.net/include)
- [require](http://php.net/require)
- [Sessions](http://php.net/sessions)

Answer (score 0):

Pass data as `GET` parameter

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['data'])) {

 $bar = $_GET['data']; // data comes from a html form on another page.

 $str = strtoupper($bar);
 echo $str;
 header("Location: script.php?data={$str}");
}

?>
```

But this will make `script.php` run immediately after current file.

Answer (score 0):

you can do
    `php script.php $str`; 
to invoke script.php with your string as a command line argument.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php